# When is a sequentially closed cone, closed?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $X$ be a locally convex, Hausdorff topological vector space and $C\subseteq X$ a convex cone, which is sequentially closed. What are criteria, that would imply that $C$ is closed (in the topology of X)?Are there also "testifyable" criteria?